# Proving that a function is injective or not

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

a) prove that $f(x)= x^2+2x+2$ is injective
b) prove that $g(x) = sin (πx)$ is injective

what i've tried is

$a) \quad f(x) = x^2+2x+2$

$$f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies  x_1^2+2x_1=x_2^2+2x_2 \implies  x_1^2-x_2^2 +2x_1-2x_2=0$$
$$\implies (x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)+2(x_1-x_2)=0 \quad (x_1+x_2)= -2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not injective, indeed

- $f(x)=x^2+2x+2=2 \implies$ $x=0$ and $x=-2$
- $g(x)=\sin (\pi x)=1 \implies x=\frac12+2k$

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can you please explain it to me ?, because i dont understand. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @didibedu Recall that by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Definition) $f$ is injective  when $$f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$$ that is equivalent to $$a\neq b \implies f(a) \neq f(b)$$ but for the functions here we find $f(0)=f(-2)=2$ and $g(1/2)=g(5/2)=1$.

Comment: aah ok i see thanks for the explanation i understand it now

Comment: @didibedu The best way is to think to the graph and intersect that with horizontal lines to show that more than $1$ solution exist. That's the best way to disprove injectivity.

Comment: can u answer one more question prove that f(x) = 4x+ 5 is injective. thanks in advance

Comment: @didibedu You can ask for a new answer of course!

Comment: if u dont mind ,can u explain how do you get x = 0 and x= -2 and x= 1/2 +2k ? thanks

Comment: @didibedu We know that $f(x)$ is a parabola and of course we have horizontal lines intersecting it. Choosing $f(x)=2$ is fine since the $2$ cancels out and we need to solve $x^2+2x=0$.

Comment: @didibedu For $g(x)$ we know that it is periodic and that $g(x)=1$ is reached for $\sin (\pi/2+2n\pi)$.

Comment: @didibedu We only need to make a clever choice and it depends from the functions we are considering.

Comment: can you show me how you do it step by step if u dont mind thanks